# Warning on missing initializer inside a structure

Tags: c++

I have the following code in C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
class X {
  private:
   struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
   } myStruct{};
};

int main() {
  X x;
}
```

When I want to compile it with gcc 4.8.2, I have the following errors:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wunused -Wunused-value -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-label -Wunused-function sample.cpp -o out

warning: missing initializer for member 'X::<anonymous struct>::a'
[-Wmissing-field-initializers]
   } myStruct{};
              ^

warning: missing initializer for member 'X::<anonymous struct>::b'
[-Wmissing-field-initializers]
   } myStruct{};
              ^
```

I thought my compiler would automatically set the variables `a` and `b` to 0...

Comment: Maybe you could post the minimal code that actually produced the error so that we don't have to type what we think you're trying?

Comment: It is a simple class with a private structure... what should I add to the sample ?

Comment: Default initialization happens when declaring variables, not when declaring classes.

Comment: `[...]` doesn't compile.  Your sample should be all the code that you pass to the compiler. so that we can copy, paste into a compiler, and see the error for ourselves.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No warning [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b9bd3b584fd84b1).

Comment: @Jarod42 can you try with -Wextra ?

Comment: @klaus: same, as you can see I explicitly added `-Wmissing-field-initializers`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I updated the sample with the warnings that produce the error.

Comment: You should add what compiler version you're using and post a [mcve]. There's no reason for posting code that won't compile for something as simple as this. I believe recent versions of gcc have fixed this warning for list initialization.

Comment: My code is compiling and I added the compiler version I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought my compiler would automatically set the variables `a` and `b` to 0...

That is true. This initialization is called aggregate initialization and in your case it initializes them to zero.

Personally, I hate this warning, because I find it annoying and always turn it off. I guess it is useful if you want the compiler to warn you when you add a member to your class and you forgot to initialize it. Of course, the compiler can't read your mind and see that you intentionally didn't initialize them because you want them to be zero.

So, ignore and move on :).

Comment: You can also omit the `{}` and get default initialisation, which [apparently doesn't warn](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b9bd3b584fd84b1)

Comment: @Caleth are you sure about this ? It won't warn but I am not sure it will be correctly initialized.

Comment: @Caleth Don't know about the warnings but this doesn't do the right thing, as default initialization doesn't initialize those integer types to zero.

Comment: Oh wow. Talk about worst of both worlds :(